# Vb.Net CheckBox Column Not Displaying

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I am trying to simply add a CheckBox Column to my DataGridView but have been unsuccessful in trying to do so.

```
'setup table
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        sdrReader = cmdShowSection.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(sdrReader)


        'set DGV1 source to dts
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        Dim column As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        With column
            .HeaderText = "Hello"
            .Name = "Hello"
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
            .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
            .CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige
        End With

        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, column)
```

When I run this the background for the first column is Beige but the CheckBox does not show up. I tried running this same code on a blank form with a blank DGV and it worked fine, no problem. I am not sure what I am doing that it doesn't like right now.

Comment: Does the header text `Hello` display or no?

Comment: Yea the header text displays

Comment: If you change the back color to yellow, does the check box show up?

Comment: Pretty unclear to what column in the data source it is supposed to be bound to.  Probably unclear to the DGV as well.  Try moving the DataSource assignment *after* you inserted the column.

Comment: No on the yellow, I also tried moving the DataSource assignment to after and that did not work either. This is really weird. I mean maybe I should not be assigning the data source like this then be manipulating the DGV. I really don't care where it is bound to right now I just want to get it to show up on the DGV at any column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling over this for the better part of the day the problem was that the width was too small for the column to display the checkbox. I set the column width to fit it and walah! It worked! So make sure that the width is truly set to what is supposed to be if you are having a similar problem.